# dynamixel_workbench: message fields for single_manger to multi_port

Tags: dynamixel, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS kinetic on  Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (and kernal name 4.13.0-32-generic). I am working with the **dynamixel_workbench** stack. Specifically, I have a MX-106, an MX-64, and another MX-64 daisy-chained.

I want to get a rough estimate of torque output of motors over time. The message published to the topic `/dynamixel/MX` when I run `single_manager.launch` contains Present_Load, Present_Voltage, and Present_Temperature. I am interested in knowing these values when I run 3 motors.

When I run `roslaunch my_dynamixel_workbench_tutorial multi_port.launch` to control my 3 motors, the message published to `/dynamixel_state` does not contain those same fields I am interested in.

Is there a straightforward way to have the voltage/load/temperature fields published for multi_port (ideally without delving through the source code and creating my own custom overlay)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287136/dynamixel_workbench:-message-fields-for-single_manger-to-multi_port/) by [RobotRob](https://answers.ros.org/users/34079/robotrob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

You can add your interest state. But this is only way to open the source code.

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench/blob/master/dynamixel_workbench_controllers/src/multi_port.cpp#L115

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRob](https://answers.ros.org/users/34079/robotrob/) on 2018-04-01**:
just to clarify, adding `dynamixel_state[cnt].Present_Load        =dxl_wb_[port_cnt]->itemRead(dxl_id_[port_cnt][index], "Present_Load");` to this list will work? Should I also have to edit the message file that is used to include an additional field?